# Compile time assertion as part of an expression but without _Static_assert

Tags: c

Ultimately, I want a compile-time-const macro that in itself includes an assertion.

With a real `_Static_assert`, I can do something like

```
#define CEXPR_MACRO_WITH_ASSERTION(Assertion) sizeof(struct{char c; _Static_assert(Assertion,""); })?0:42
```

(meant for stuff like "compile-time-assert" that the macro value computation won't overflow on any target, and I'd like to keep the assertion in the macro so that it's tightly coupled with the value) but compilers like tcc don't have static asserts so I'd need to emulate it.

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(Cexpr,Msg) extern STATIC_ASSERT[(Cexpr)?1:-1]
```

is a common way to do it but with that `extern` I can't use it in a struct so I could split it in two

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(Cexpr,Msg) extern STATIC_ASSERT_(Cexpr,Msg)
#define STATIC_ASSERT_(Cexpr,Msg) char STATIC_ASSERT[sizeof(char [((Cexpr))?1:-1])] /*ignore Msg for simplicity's sake*/
```

and use the underscore version in the `CEXPR_MACRO_WITH_ASSERTION`, but in function context, this will give false positives on compilers that support structs with VLAs in them:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(Cexpr,Msg) extern STATIC_ASSERT_(Cexpr,Msg)
#define STATIC_ASSERT_(Cexpr,Msg) char STATIC_ASSERT[sizeof(char [((Cexpr))?1:-1])]
#define CEXPR_MACRO_WITH_ASSERTION(Assert) (sizeof(struct{char c; STATIC_ASSERT_(Assert,""); })?0:42)

int main(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    CEXPR_MACRO_WITH_ASSERTION(x);
} //compiles on tcc and gcc (clang rejects it because of the vla in a struct)
```

so I effectively need:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT_(Cexpr,Msg) char STATIC_ASSERT[sizeof(char [((Cexpr)&&ENFORCE_ICEXPR(Cexpr))?1:-1])]
```

Now I realize on tcc in particular, `ENFORCE_ICEXPR` (enforce integer constant expression) could be simply replaced with `__builtin_constant_p` but I was curious if I could do it without the platform dependency.

So I thought I could test `Cexpr` by trying to assign it to an `enum` constant and I came up with:

```
#define ENFORCE_Z(X) _Generic(0LL+(X),ullong:(X),llong:(X)) /*could be just `+(X)` cuz I don't care about floats*/
#define ENFORCE_ICEXPR(X) sizeof( void (*)(enum { ENFORCE_ICEXPR = (int)ENFORCE_Z(X) }  ) )
```

but this gets gcc and clang complaining (unsilencably in gcc's case)  about the enum not being visible outside of the declaration (which, incidentally, was the intention here) so I resorted to

```
#define ENFORCE_ICEXPR(X) sizeof(enum { BX_cat(ENFORCE_ICEXPR__,__COUNTER__) = (int)ENFORCE_Z(X) })
```

relying on the nonstandard magic macro, `__COUNTER__`.

My question is, is there a better way to write `ENFORCE_ICEXPR(X)`?

Comment: Perl [uses a bit-field instead of an array](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/maint-5.28/perl.h#L3431-L3440). No compiler implements variable length bit-fields.

Comment: @melpomene Excellent. `#define ENFORCE_ICEXPR(X) sizeof(struct { int f:!!(X); })
` works splendidly. I will accept it as an answer if you wish to collect your points. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl [uses a bit-field instead of an array](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/maint-5.28/perl.h#L3431-L3440) to define a `static_assert` fallback:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT_2(COND, SUFFIX) \
    typedef struct { \
        unsigned int _static_assertion_failed_##SUFFIX : (COND) ? 1 : -1; \
    } _static_assertion_failed_##SUFFIX PERL_UNUSED_DECL
#define STATIC_ASSERT_1(COND, SUFFIX) STATIC_ASSERT_2(COND, SUFFIX)
#define STATIC_ASSERT_DECL(COND) STATIC_ASSERT_1(COND, __LINE__)
```

No compiler implements variable length bit-fields.